# Google App Engine performance setting : Some performance settings must be changed via Module configuration files

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Google App Engine performance setting is not available for the application, it is displaying as Some performance settings must be changed via Module configuration files.

My question is, in my current application I am not using module, so it should have performance setting sliders displayed? Or I need to set it through configuration file?

Comment: You may want to edit your question, it is unclear what the words "application I am not using module" mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has disabled the performance panel. The only option left is to configure through appengine-web.xml.

Thanks.